# MySQL - How to see previous IP's which have connected with database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to find the IP addresses which have previously interacted with my database. Is there a way for me to do this as it is part of a college assignment but can only find examples showing the TOTAL amount of connections, but not the actual IP addresses that have connected.

Answer (score 0):

Besides a more specialized logging/monitoring service outside of the MySQL daemon itself I think the only way you can achieve this is by turning general logging ON.

You need to include --general_log as a flag when running the daemon or set it on startup `SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';`

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/query-log.html for details

Comment: I'm assuming that I would need to have access to the server files to obtain this file log, or can I obtain this through phpmyadmin?

Comment: I think in the example of users who are logging into the db via phpmyadmin I would without more sophisticated logging in place (i.e. Stackdriver, Splunk, etc) I would hunt down POST and phpMyAdmin from the Apache logs.  NOT a very good solution I must admit.  The MySQL general log is the way to go or log connections to 3306 via iptables.

Comment: @Luxry It occurred to me you may be referring to how to access the general log once turned on.  In modern MySQL installations, this log will be written to the general_log table in the mysql database which you can access via phpMyAdmin.  Sorry for the confusion.